# create image from hard disk without free space (linux)

Tags: linux, image

I want to create image from hard disk without free space (useless space) in linux(ex3 type).

I've been tried to create image with **dd** command but this command gave us total size of hard disk.

I need data on this hard disk without free space.

thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like [Partimage](http://www.partimage.org/) might be what you are looking for?

Comment: I use Partimage and this is the best way to go.

Comment: For a filesystem-agnostic solution, you can fill the filesystem with nulls ("dd if=/dev/zero of=/some/file ; rm /some/file") and then use dd's "conv=sparse" option.  The downsides are: 1) This will be less efficient than a tool which knows the filesystem; and 2) so far as I can tell, using anything other than dd's default 512-byte block size will cause this to not work (or at least miss enough sparse space as to be useless), which will dramatically increase the time for dd to do its job.

Comment: @GeoffFritz 3) This won't work when any of the filesystems that the image needs to reside on or be transported via don't support sparse files.

Comment: no ext4 support tho

Answer (score 6):

One option would be to create the file system image as a [**sparse file**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file). You could first run an utility such as [zerofree](https://frippery.org/uml/) on your ext3 file system to make sure all free blocks are filled with zeros, and then just image the disk with `dd` and pipe the image through `cp` with the `--sparse=always` option to force it to create a sparse file:

```
dd if=/dev/whatever | cp --sparse=always /dev/stdin disk.image
```

Comment: This is just crazy enough to work.  I wouldn't have thought of piping the byte stream through cp.  Have you done this before or are you anticipating that it will work?

Comment: I had not actually done anything like this before, but I did test the idea with a dummy ext3 file system image before posting, and it seems to work. If `dd` had an option to create sparse files, the `cp` trick would be unnecessary. Apparently such an option was proposed a couple of years ago, but since the man page does not mention it, I assume the patch was not accepted: http://www.mail-archive.com/bug-coreutils@gnu.org/msg11795.html

Answer (score 1):

If you're using LVM, clonezilla is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

+1 Partimage .  The [system rescue CD](http://www.sysresccd.org) might help if you just want to save something.  Plug in a removable drive and/or a network mount once it has booted and write the image to disk.

If you're trying to image an entire drive for transport, don't forget to save the partition table (and the boot sector for a bootable)

Answer (score 0):

I use partimage for get image also this program worke with command.

If you get image by bash script you work with this and `dumpe2fs` or `xfsdump` commands.