# using dd command to get hard drive image

Tags: linux, backup, hard-drive

Is there a way to use 'dd' command to get a hard drive image that ignores the free space on the hard drive?

Comment: Similar question: http://serverfault.com/questions/93667/create-image-from-hard-disk-without-free-space-linux/93692

Answer (score 6):

No.  dd is a block-by-block copy that ignores content (nothing is ever free, just not yet overwritten).  If you want to ignore free space you have to use a logical imaging tool such as Ghost, [Acronis](http://www.acronis.com/download/) or similar.

Comment: Do you know any command base application to do this? I need this application to run from the live linux.

Comment: Depending on the filesystem, there may be a utility which understands the filesystem structure and can dump only blocks in use, for example `dumpe2fs` or `xfsdump`.

Comment: how use this commands to get backup without the free space?

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out that is not possible with dd.  It's a very low level tool and just copies the bitstream from one device to another or file.  [Partimage](http://www.partimage.org/Main_Page) however is capable of doing what you're looking for and it supports a [long list of file systems](http://www.partimage.org/Supported-Filesystems).  The easiest way to use this is to download the [clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) livecd.  It's a livecd that has wrapped partimage with an easy to use wizard.

Answer (score 1):

If you first make sure that the free space on the hard drive is filled with zeros, it's possible to convert the disk image into a **sparse file**, where the zeros won't take up storage space. Details in [an another answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/93667/create-image-from-hard-disk-without-free-space-linux/93692#93692).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use file system level utilities that recognise used and free space.  One program that uses a nice GUI for accomplishing this is GParted, but there are several GUI and command line tools to copy, resize, and modify file systems.

Answer (score 0):

It was my understanding that `dd` does a bit-by-bit copy, so you'd get free space and all.

So, no. I don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

No, `dd` knows nothing about filesystems so can't tell what parts of the disc are or aren't in use.

If most of the disc that is unused has *never* been used since a full-format (so is still all zeroes), running the output of `dd` through `gzip` will nicely compress it away to nothing, though.