# Reduce xen image disk usage

Tags: linux, compression, dd, sparse-files

Two cases:

1.If making hdd image using dd and copy it trough nfs to another server:

```
mount -o ro,remount /
dd if=/dev/sda bs=64K | gzip -c > /share/test.img.gz
```

then after gunzip I get 20Gb (for ex.) file, filled w/zeroes at the end:

```
du -h /md/share/test.img
21G /md/share/test.img
```

2. If I create empty image using dd:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/md/share/test2.img bs=1024k seek=20480 count=0
```

I got:

```
du -h /md/share/test2.img
0 /md/share/test2.img
ls -lah /md/share/test2.img
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 20G Aug 2 14:46 /md/share/test2.img
```

After mounting this to guest, I can use all 20G in any way I want, and IMG size is always equal it's actual contents, without any "zeroes" eating my array space.

Question: how I can reduce disk image size for case 1?

Answer: if dd supports `conv=sparse` attribute, it must be used in addition to `tar --sparse`. If not, update `coreutils` and try it again. Else install package `libguestfs-tools` and run `virt-sparcify /md/share/test.img /md/share/test_sparse.img`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @sam_pan_mariusz said, the reduced-size image you're creating your "empty" image as a "sparse" file.  In order to create a sparse file from an existing block device, add the `conv=sparse` option to the `dd if=/dev/sda [...]` command that you used to make the initial image.  You will need to put the image file into `tar --sparse`, because just compressing the file image will cause the sparse chunks to be written out, making them non-sparse.

Comment: Briliant, womble! But there is no "sparse" option in my centos's dd. It looks like deprecated version (in Centos 5.11), but I found other questions with similar answers dated 2009 (http://serverfault.com/questions/93667/create-image-from-hard-disk-without-free-space-linux). It's different centos coreutils trunk or something like that? Available "conv" values are:
ascii    
ebcdic   
ibm      
block    
unblock  
lcase    
nocreat  
excl     
notrunc  
ucase    
swab     
noerror  
sync              
fdatasync
fsync

Comment: Great. https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=908980

Comment: Solution is: `yum install libguestfs-tools`, then `virt-sparsify /md/share/test.img /md/share/test_sparse.img`

Answer (score 1):

This feature is called *sparse files*. GNU `tar --sparse` handles them well, other than gzip alone.

It doesn't also hurt to use `zerofree` on the resulting image.